# How to send BAN request to Varnish via curl to double server?

Tags: php, linux, curl, magento2, varnish

I've just prepared method in PHP which send BAN request to varnish via CURL something like this:

```
 curl --header "X-Magento-Flush-All-Data: 123" -X BAN https://example.com
```

but it doesn't work at all because varnish is not cleaned. I try to accomplish situation when varnish wil be cleaned as well as via SSH using service restart varnish. Any ideas how to achieve this one? Here is my architecture

[image]

Comment: Obviously with the given architecture, you will need TWO curl requests, one for each Varnish instance.

Comment: In my case it's impossible  because on each of server I have registry in /etc/hosts which is for example 81.222.111.4 example.com and I can't modify that. Problem is that varnish is on different IP like 99.121.33.4 and I can't send curl there because I get redirect to example.com @DanielV.

Comment: Why do you really have to access Varnish for invalidation of cache with DNS? Use two curls, i.e.: ```curl --header "X-Magento-Flush-All-Data: 123" -X BAN http://1.1.1.1``` and ```curl --header "X-Magento-Flush-All-Data: 123" -X BAN http://2.2.2.2```